# Are there any browser development tools that show you what level of the DOM an element is, so I know how to select it with CSS?

Tags: css, dom

For example, If I look at an HTML tag in the Developer Tools of Chrome, FF, etc., is there a way for me to see where in the DOM an item is located *with* the level that I could use for a CSS selector?

If I go to a tag, it might have parent tr nth-child(4)...

I looked Chrome's Properties.  Is that what I am seeking?

Comment: I Chrome that is exactly what is showed ... If you righ click/Inspect the orange "Question" button here at SO, it shows: `#hmenus .nav ul li.youarehere a, #hmenus .nav ul li a:hover` ... so what is it you actually are asking?

Comment: You want to get the index of an element among its siblings?

Comment: @LGSon Maybe.  You mean right under the DOM, just above the console window?

Comment: @Oriol I think so.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not see it initially, but if you click on the Node in Chrome Developer Tools "Elements"-Panel and select Copy -> Copy XPath, you will have the Path copied containing the index of the element like this:

```
/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]
```

=> 2nd item

Comment: Actually, copy selector does more inline with what I wanted.  You pointed me there.  Thanks.